# How to do consecutive SELECTS in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

There is a database with the following tables:

```
table_1: id, atr1
table_2: id, atr2
table_3: id, table_1_id(Foreign Key), table_2_id(Foreign Key), atr3
```

The operation I want to make is a bit complicated and I can explain it doing some extra programming aside from the SQL queries.

The first part of the operation would be to get all the identifiers of table_2 in table_3 which meet some criteria.

```
SELECT table_3.table_2_id
FROM table_3
WHERE
table_3.atr3 = 'value1' AND
table_3.table_1_id = 'value2'
```

The next part would be to take each of the values I have just obtained and then use them in the following query. I would do this in a loop.

```
SELECT table_3.id, table_3.atr3, table_1.atr1, table_2.atr2
FROM table_3
JOIN table_1 ON table_3.table_1_id = table_1.id
JOIN table_2 ON table_3.table_2_id = table_2.id
WHERE
table_3.table_2_id = 'current_value_i_am_iterating_over' AND
(table_3.table_1_id = 'value4' OR
table_3.table_1_id = 'value5')
```

After the query, I would concatenate the obtained rows in an array that contains all the rows I obtain in the successive iterations of the loop.

What I would like to know is if there's a way to avoid the second loop, ideally making the whole operation in only one SQL query.

Comment: can you provide sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use simple sub query? I mean you can have

```
table_3.table_2_id = (your first query with limit 1)
```

limit 1 just to avoid multiple records return from subquery
or else you can use  `IN`

```
table_3.table_2_id IN (your first query)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can phrase the query as `in`:

```
SELECT t3.id, t3.atr3, t1.atr1, t2.atr2
FROM table_3 t3 JOIN
     table_1 t1
     ON t3.table_1_id = t1.id JOIN
     table_2 t2
     ON t3.table_2_id = t2.id
WHERE t3.table_2_id IN (SELECT table_2_id
                        FROM table_3
                        WHERE atr3 = 'value1' AND table_1_id = 'value2'
                       ) AND
      t3.table_1_id IN ('value4', 'value5');
```

This is the most direct way to add the logic into a single query.

Comment: @cha . . . That is quite true.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as (
SELECT table_3.table_2_id
FROM table_3
WHERE
table_3.atr3 = 'value1' AND
table_3.table_1_id = 'value2')

SELECT table_3.id, table_3.atr3, table_1.atr1, table_2.atr2
FROM table_3
JOIN table_1 ON table_3.table_1_id = table_1.id
JOIN table_2 ON table_3.table_2_id = table_2.id
JOIN cte on table_3.table_2_id = cte.table_2_id
WHERE
(table_3.table_1_id = 'value4' OR
table_3.table_1_id = 'value5')
```

use common table expression and add an extra join, no need to loop it.